# Is there a benefit for using a bigger warehouse in snowflake for a simple update operation?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

For example:

```
update table_name 
set uid = regex_replace (uid, '.','0') 
where uid = uid00000
```

My assumption is that there will be no spillage to disk so the only benefit is less time to execute the query.

this is as opposed to queries that spillage might occur and there might be a cost benefit to increasing the warehouse size.

My question pertains specifically to updates as simple as the one above. Updates that do not include joins, aggregations etc.

Comment: In some cases, there is a benefit. There's not enough information in the question to know one way or the other. It will depend on how many micropartitions the update needs to scan to find rows to update and how many micropartitions need to be rewritten.

Comment: There are many more advantages to a larger warehouse than simply avoiding spillage.  As @GregPavlik has pointed out, scan and write operations can be improved, as well, depending on the number of micropartitions being read/written